# running mach-o file which built for simulator on macOS 10.12

Tags: ios, xcode

I've updated macOS(10.11->10.12.6) and xcode(?->8.3.3) and now I can't run my test which was built for iPhoneSimulator. A test is a command-line executable.
It works on previous version as far as I know. Build command was not changed.

Build:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C "../build_release" -r -f ../../build/Makefile.test test_case_a
clang++ -o test_case_a.o -c -MMD -g -O2 -DUSE_PTHREAD -stdlib=libc++ -m32 -mrtm -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -Wall -std=c++11  -I../../src -I../../include -I.  ../../src/test/test_case_a.cpp
clang++ -o test_case_a.exe -g -O2 -DUSE_PTHREAD -stdlib=libc++ -m32 -mrtm -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -Wall test_case_a.o libtesttarget.dylib   -lpthread  -m32 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk/usr/lib/system -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk/usr/lib/ -miphoneos-version-min=8.0

# running:
./test_case_a.exe
dyld: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)
make[1]: *** [test_case_a] Abort trap: 6
```

From xcodebuild -sdk -version

```
iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk - Simulator - iOS 10.3 (iphonesimulator10.3)
SDKVersion: 10.3
Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk
PlatformVersion: 10.3
PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
ProductBuildVersion: 14E8301
ProductCopyright: 1983-2017 Apple Inc.
ProductName: iPhone OS
ProductVersion: 10.3.1
```

Comment: When you open the App with the new Xcode you should upgrade the Application Settings (Editor->Validate settings)? If you have still have the problem, check the new compiler settings. I suggest to compare the old version of the project with the new one using Beyond compare or something similar.. (folder compare). This can help you to understand what is changed. Probably some new setting added in the last version of the compiler with a default value not valid for your project

Comment: Thank you for suggestions but I build application directly via makefiles; I have no any xcode project; All compile commands are provided above